# looking for help extracting the last dozen entries that match grep command

Tags: linux, grep, php

I have a log file that I pull data to a private web page to monitor my router. 
There are alot of entries. for each access control list. right now I have a simple php script. I only want the last 12 entries of the grep iWiSP-In. There could be 100's of them in the file. using Tail -n XX in place of cat won't work since there may not be any entries in that time frame. There has to be simple answer that is escaping me.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('cat /var/log/_gateway-syslog.log | grep iWiSP-In');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: `tail` **after** `grep`? `grep iWiSP-In /var/log/_gateway-syslog.log | tail -n 12`

Comment: That did it. I had tried several variations and it didn't work. I know it was something  simple . Thank you steeldriver